# Vue Routing isn't returning blog posts

Tags: django, vue.js, vue-router

I am unable to return data once I click on the blog post. I believe that it is an issue with routing.

When clicking to a blog post we no content is return.

Comment: You need to provide at least some part of your code so people can be able to try to help you.

Comment: Giving 2 lines of code is not enough. Image yourself in our shoes, how would somebody be able to debug that with no code, no context, no config. Just few characters and a possible idea. Please put more effort. [ask]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.